# Google Maps Embed API Not Centering Pins

Tags: html, css, google-maps, iframe

I am building a website that uses Google's Mapping API Embed V1.0, and the coordinates that I specified are showing correctly, however, the point is not in the center of the mapping view.

Photo of Problem:

[image: Off Center Maps]

iFrame Code:

```
<iframe class="sectionMap" width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAGJVo8xnxXbEICl5IuDAbmWIBsE0cFKVQ&amp;q=42.3599,-71.0655&amp;zoom=18&amp;maptype=satellite"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
.sectionMap{
/*
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
*/
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #ccc;
}
```

Here is a sample page from the web app:

```
<section id="williamMonroeTrotterHouse" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="appHeader"><a href="#landmarks" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-theme="a">Back</a>
        <h1>William Monroe Trotter House</h1>
    </header>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p><span class="sectionTitle">Location: </span>97 Sawyer Ave., Dorchester</p>
        <p><span class="sectionTitle">Description: </span>Home of African-American journalist and Harvard graduate William Monroe Trotter. Trotter publisher The Guardian, and meetings of African-American activists, W. E. B. Du Bois among them, took place at this house.</p>
        <img src="Landmark_Photos/WIlliam_Monroe_Trotter_House.jpg" class="sectionPhoto">
        <br>
        <iframe class="sectionMap" width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAGJVo8xnxXbEICl5IuDAbmWIBsE0cFKVQ&amp;q=42.3127,-71.0624&amp;zoom=18&amp;maptype=satellite"></iframe>
    </div>
</section>
```

Any ideas why this is not centering?

*PS: I don't believe this is a duplicate post, as Google recently updated the mapping api and the answers to previous questions do not work.*

Comment: What sets the size of the iframe?

Comment: Thanks for your reply:    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;

Comment: Seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/XADL4/

Comment: Can't see where is the suppoised "point of interest". Top-left corner?

Comment: This is weird. On JS Fiddle, it is showing in the middle, but on Safari it is not. Could this be a conflict with JQuery Mobile?

Comment: Check (css +html ) it is visible, display "not" none, set size of iframe and let's see what happend (Don't know why, but I had this -solved- issue before)

Comment: I tried to re-adjust the size of the iFrame, and the issue is still present. Is there a JQuery command that can serenader an iFrame?

Comment: I think you didn't understood what I mean: BEFORE the map script is called SET width and height of the iframe AND check it does have "display" and it's "visible". It does not work _after_, just _before_, because when iframe is 0x0 sized top left corner is it's center.

Comment: Ok, I have now put the size of the iFrame into the tag: <iframe class="sectionMap" width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" but it is still not centering the pin. Any ideas?

Comment: And please post some more of the surrounding html and the css applied.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the surrounding html and the entire code for the JQM page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fiddle having exactly you code works fine in my Safari version (5.1.7). Wich version are you having problems with? The only reason I could imagine is the "tricky" centering with position and margin. I'd try `margin:0 auto;` for centering, without the position relative, top & margin. Or go the old way: `display:inline-block` inside a div with `text-align:center`. IMHO this last one is the most cross-browser.

```
.sectionMapWrapper{
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}

.sectionMap{
display: inline-block;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #ccc;
}
```

EDIT:

If it didn't solve the problem check if you have some kind of library (or your own function) that could make your iframe "display: none".

If it have no layout (display:none) when the content is loaded it's size is 0x0 for the iframe script, and the center is at ... 0/x , 0/x. Keep display block until content is loaded, then you can hide it with display:none.

Under a similar situation I worked around this placing the iframe inside a 0x0 sized div with overflow hidden (at style attribute). When sure of iframe content is loaded fire a function that set the iframe display to none and delete the wrapper div style attribute. (or similar, depending of the additional behaviour you need). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am running Safari 7.0.4 with 10.9.3 and iOS 7 Safari.

Comment: @Jake I edited the answer. If there's a "live" version I'd like to check the whole thing if possible.

Comment: Ok, here is the url to a beta: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B4/ please click on any tab (the first one is a bit buggy) and a details screen will show with a Google maps. It is generated from js/landmarks.js. Thanks for taking a look at it.

Comment: It's in jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css line 1336. That's the display none that make this thing happend. The whole sections have display:none. Hope you can adapt the workarround in the anwser to your needs. Just try comment out this "display:none", maybe that's all you have to do.

Comment: ...and it's not a good idea to make all those iframe be loaded cause "yes". I'd wait to the user click to insert each one. That solve both problems. Consider how much bandwith could you make waste a mobile user loading all those maps that probably he will never see.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will re-work the Javascript to load only when tapped.